# "elif" syntax error

Tags: python, syntax-error

I'm building a game where the computer know which farm animal your have in mind. He ask you questions to guess your farm animal. But I got an error and I don't know how to fix it.

My code:

```
qs_one = raw_input("Do your animal walk on two legs? answar 'yes' or 'no'")
if qs_one == "yes":
    qs_two = raw_input("Do your animal have a white skin? answar 'yes' or 'no'")
    if qs_two == "yes":
        print "Your animal is a goose!"
    elif qs_two == "no":
        print "Your animal is a chicken!"
    else:
        print "Error, try again."
elif qs_one == "no":
    qs_two = raw_input("Do your animal have horns? answar 'yes' or 'no'")
    if qs_two == "yes":
        qs_tree = raw_input("Do your animal have stains? answar 'yes' or 'no'")
        if qs_tree == "yes":
            print "Your animal is a cow!"
        elif qs_tree == "no":
            qs_four = raw_input("Do your animal have goatee? answar 'yes' or 'no'")
            if qs_four == "yes":
                print "Your animal is a goat!"
            elif qs_four == "no":
                print "Your animal is a bull!"
            else:
                print "Error, try again."
        else:
            print "Error, try again."
    elif qs_two == "no":
        qs_tree = raw_input("Do your animal have a pink skin? answar 'yes' or 'no'")
        if qs_tree == "yes":
            print "Your animal is a pig!"
        elif:  # <- ERROR HERE
            qs_four = raw_input("Can you ride your animal? answar 'yes' or 'no'")
            if qs_four == "yes":
                print "Your animal is a horse!"
            elif qs_four == "no":
                qs_five = raw_input("Does your animal have big ears? answar 'yes' or 'no'")
                if qs_five == "yes":
                    "Your animal is a rabbit!"
                elif qs_five == "no":
                    "Your animal is a sheep!"
                else:
                    print "Error, try again."
            else:
                print "Error, try again."
        else:
            print "Error, try again."
    else:
        print "Error, try again."
else:
    print "Error, try again."
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "python", line 30
elif:
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax``
```

Comment: Your indentation is all over the place. Please make sure you have the *correct* indentation in your question for us to be able to reproduce your issue.

Comment: I think the command you are looking for is else because elif is a else if statement that requires a condition.

Answer (score 4):

You need to have a condition to an `elif`, i.e.

```
elif condition_is_true:
    *do something*
```

I think what you want to do is to use `elif qs_tree=='no':`.  If "yes", it's a pig, if "no", it is something else and every other answer should give the "Error, try again"-message.

Comment: Probably just needs an `else:` since preceding was `if qs_tree == "yes":` to a `'yes'` or `'no'` question.

Comment: @martineau I think he wants a yes/no/else-question, since the only two valid answers are yes and no.  Everything else has to be caught by the `else`.